# VBP file tags value

Tags: vb6

I have open VBP file in notepad and there are differet tags over there like `CompatibleMode`, `Command32`, `HelpContextID`, `ServerSupportFiles`, `CompilationType`, `OptimizationType`, `FavorPentiumPro(tm)`, `CodeViewDebugInfo`, `StartMode`.

I wanted to know the meaning of this different tags. Please revert if you have any idea. I found on google but didnt found anything.

Comment: I think you didn't googled it properly. Here is a good explanation of VBP file; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716294(v=vs.60).aspx

Answer (score 4):

All these tags are referring to your project properties.
When opening your project in VB6 goto the "Project" menu and click on "projectname Properties...". From there on the VB6 help can tell you everything you want to know.

For example

> Version Compatibility
>
> Allows you to set the level of version compatibility
>
> No Compatibility — Compatibility not enforced.
>
> Project Compatibility — If checked, the Location box is active and
>   allows you to search for the file with which this project is to be
>   compatible. If cleared, the Location box is not available. For all
>   ActiveX project types, Project Compatibility is checked by default.
>
> Binary Compatibility — Useful for maintaining compatibility among
>   projects that have been compiled using your component.